# I tried to change a git config, but it won't change. Instead it shows both settings ?! 

Tags: git, git-config

When I do

```
git config --list
```

I get

```
core.filemode=true
```

so I do

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

and now when I do list the configuration I got

```
core.filemode=false
core.filemode=true
```

What does this mean? And how can I successfully change it to false only

EDIT: Doing `git config --list --show-origin` indicates that

```
file:/home/me/.gitconfig core.filemode=false
file:.git/config  core.filemode=true
```

So which is it?

Comment: Kansai, you got three long and thorough answers (i.e. people spent time on this for you), and from your comments it's solved. You should do the courtesy of accepting one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git supports both local and global configurations. Local configurations take precedence over global. See

```
file:/home/me/.gitconfig core.filemode=false  # Your Global Config
file:.git/config  core.filemode=true          # Your Local Config
```

From the Git Configuration Page:

> Finally, Git looks for configuration values in the configuration file
> in the Git directory (.git/config) of whatever repository you’re
> currently using. These values are specific to that single repository,
> and represent passing the --local option to git config. If you don’t
> specify which level you want to work with, this is the default.
> https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Thus, to set it to false for your repository, simply set:

```
git config --local core.filemode false
```

Note, you can also edit `.git/config` like a normal file in any editor of your choice.

Comment: I did just `git config core.filemode false` and it worked too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the `--global` flag. There is a global `.gitconfig` in your home directory, and there is optionally a local one in the repo. That is what `--show-origin` is showing you.

As in expect in all such global/local configuration systems, the local one will override the global for all settings that overlap.

If you want `core.filemode` to be false, you have three options (i.e. ONLY do one of these):

1. Set it to false in the repo local config by doing the same command as before but without `--global`:

   ```
   git config core.filemode false
   ```

   This works because new settings are made local by default.
   If you did not expect to have local settings, you might have
   created this file by accident by omitting `--global` in the past.
2. Unset it in the repo local config so that the global one will apply:

   ```
   git config --unset core.filemode
   ```
3. Delete the repo local config if you want no local settings, only the global. Or to be safe, rename the file to something else until you are sure there is nothing in it you need -- if you do you could copy those setting to global if that is appropriate.

   > ℹ️ I included this option for completeness. But there are almost always repo-specific values, e.g. configuration of remotes and remote tracking branches, so it you probably should use option 2 for settings that should defer to your global config.

Comment: I suppose in #1 you meant `git config core.filemode false` right?

Comment: Thank you! I cut and pasted your command to reflect I was using the same one, but with a change, but forgot to change it!

Comment: I gave you all three options because you should figure out which one makes sense. If you set it to false locally, then you later want a global core.filemode to apply to all your projects, you'll wonder why this project doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

[Inigo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263427/1256452) and [armitus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263409/1256452) both mentioned the reason for the duplication—namely, that the setting is now in both your global `.gitconfig` and your local `.git/config` files, and that the more-local setting overrides the more-global one.

There are two other points of interest here though.  One is specific to `core.filemode` (aka `core.fileMode`; [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) spells this both ways).  The other is generally applicable to certain Git configuration settings.

When a Git command starts up, it reads through as many Git configuration files as apply.  There is a standard set of at least three: the system-wide configuration, often in `/etc/gitconfig` or `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig` for instance, then your own global file, often in `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `$HOME/.config/git/config` or similar, and finally the per-repository configuration in `.git/config`.  *Most* settings retain only the *last value*, so if, e.g., `/etc/gitconfig` sets `color.grep.filename = red`, but your global file sets `color.grep.filename = blue`, `git grep` file names will be in blue—unless your local file overrides this yet again.  If your local file has multiple *entries* in it, the last one overrides.

Some Git settings, however, *accumulate*.  For instance, `remote.origin.fetch` is normally set in your local `.git/config` to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, in a normal (full) clone.  A single-branch clone, however, will have this set to `+refs/heads/somebranch:refs/remotes/origin/somebranch`.  This is what makes the clone a single-branch clone in the first place.  Using `git remote set-branches --add`, you can add *more individual branches*, one by one; each one adds *one more* `remote.origin.fetch` entry.

This kind of accumulation applies regardless of which file(s) contain the setting.  This means that it's possible to set up Git to copy all GitHub pull requests using a `fetch` setting in your global Git configuration file.  (I don't *recommend* this—it accumulates a lot of cruft, for instance—but it is *possible*.)

Last, let's note that `core.filemode` controls whether Git believes that `chmod +x` and `chmod -x` operations, performed on files in your working tree, should be copied back to entries in Git's index when you run `git add`.  For *new* files, it controls whether the `x` bit in [`lstat` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) results makes this Git index entry be `mode 100755` (+x) or `mode 100644` (-x).  **Git sets this at the time you create a new repository** with `git init` or `git clone` **based on the behavior of your operating system and the file system in which the repository is being created.**  Changing the setting can be useful for some special cases, but in general, is unwise: be very sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: good info about overrides vs accumulation. Thanks!

Comment: I have a global setting that I wish to override locally, but it seems to be an accumulating one.  Is there a way to force an override?

Comment: @trademark: some command(s) have a trick for clearing out accumulations, but there's no completely general mechanism.  The only one I know of that actually has the clearing mechanism is `credential.helper`, where `git config --add credential.helper ''` adds an entry that erases previous entries (so that local entries will now override `git config --global` for instance). This is documented in [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).